# How to upload files from jQuery to a php server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, upload

i want to send the values of the files array to my PHP server, i try to do that but jquery returns undefined, offcourse i still new to jquery and here the code :

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$stars_settings['attachments']['max_number'];$i++)
{
    $cls = ($i == 1 && in_array('attachments',$_SESSION['iserror'])) ? ' class="isError" ' : '';
    echo '<input id="attachment['.$i.']" type="file" name="attachment['.$i.']" size="50" '.$cls.' /><br />';
}
```

how can i submit this `id="attachment['.$i.']"` ?

Comment: Clarify your question, it's absolutely unclear.

Comment: as you know i jquery we define for example var test = $("#attachment").value();  but in my case attachmment['.$i.']

Comment: @HassanMostafa what you want to achieve with this array in jquey.

Comment: i want to upload  files in array according to $stars_settings['attachments']['max_number'] in the for loop above

Comment: `$( 'input:file' ).each(...)`

Comment: $( 'input:file' ).each('#attachment');  i test in this state but not work

Comment: Then RTFM http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @HassanMostafa can you please put all of your jquery code in your question?

Answer (score -1):

You **cannot** upload files with just plain ol' jQuery.

You need to be smart about it, either create your own methods to handle the uploads, or use a library/plugin that someone else created.

---

For example you can do:

```
// Originally solved by Tim Branyen in his drop file plugin
// http://dev.aboutnerd.com/jQuery.dropFile/jquery.dropFile.js
// Allows for datatransfer and file uploads
jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
```

Then when someone drops a file into a dive from their desktop, you can do:

```
$(document).on('drop', '.attachments', function(event) {
    var dt, files;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    attachments.removeClass('hover');
    dt = event.dataTransfer;
    files = dt.files;
    // Do something with the raw files
});
```

Here is an example of a function you can use to handle raw files:

```
function handleFile(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
       var dataURL = event.target.result;
       //upload the file via ajax
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```